# “Kaffee schwarz” or “schwarzer Kaffee”

Tags: adjective, noun, word-order

I’m studying German using the book *Berliner Platz* and I read in it someone saying:

> Ich trinke Kaffee schwarz.

Shouldn’t *schwarz* (adjective) go before the noun *Kaffee* as in

> Ich trinke schwarzen Kaffee.

Comment: Apparantly it’s written down, so it’s clear. Had it been spoken, it could also have been ‘Ich trinke Kaffee. Schwarz’, i.e. two full stops. It would be distinguishable by intonation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Schwarz" serves as an adverb here. "Den Kaffee schwarz trinken" has a special meaning of drinking coffee without milk.

Comment: That's what I thought but when I searched for "schwarz" in the dictionary I didn't found anything about it being an adverb. Nevertheless, Duden has the same example, so I just have to accept it.

Comment: The first sentence also strongly indicates a habit, so in would translate to English *I'm used to drink coffee without milk*. In the second sentence this could be just a coincidence and would more relate to a specific sort of coffee (which is a bit strange, since I know of no other colors)