# Choosing “die Würstchen warm” “over “die warmen Würstchen”

Tags: word-order, adjective, adverb, idiomaticity

I have seen that in both German and English, adjectives  can appear before and after the noun.  Example:

> (1) Er isst die warmen Würstchen.  – attributive use of adjective (my version)
> (2) Er isst die Würstchen warm. – predicative use of adjective (example from grammar book)<sup>1</sup>

or another situation from my side:

> (3) Ich kaufte das billige Auto.
>
> (4) Ich kaufte das Auto billig.

From my subjective view, sentence (1) is neutral while (2) can be used to give the sense that there were a range of scenarios (e.g. hot, cold, warm),  but he ate the franks when they were warm.  Similary, sentence (3) is neutral, while (4) gives the sense that the car could have been something other than cheap (e.g. expensive, hard to purchase) but I bought the car when it was cheap.

There is a [related GSE post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27725/kaffee-schwarz-or-schwarzer-kaffee) that discusses “*Kaffee schwarz*” or “*schwarzer Kaffee*” and the explanation given there is that *schwarz* is an adverb and a special case of drinking coffee without milk.  However, my grammar book<sup>1</sup> makes no mention of adverbs and also states:

> The use of an uninflected adjective after the noun is poetic,
> e.g.: *O Täler **weit**, o Höhen! (Eichendorff)*.  However it has become
> frequent as a stylistic device in advertising and technical language,
> cf. DUDEN (1995: 256), e.g.:
>
> Henkel **trocken**
> Schrankwand in Eiche **rustikal** oder Kiefer **natur**

I don’t think these use cases would be the entire scope, since examples (2) and (4) would be valid as part of every day usage.

I would be interested to know when you would choose “*die Würstchen warm*” “over “*die warmen Würstchen*”

Source: 1. „Hammer’s German Grammar and Usage, 3rd Edition“ Durrell, Martin.  Arnold 1996, pages 118 – 119.

Comment: Careful: "Ich kaufte das billige Auto." is not the same as "Ich kaufte das Auto billig.". The first one states that you buy a cheap car. The other states that the overall event of buying a car was cheap. Similar for the "Würstchen"-example.

Comment: Sentences 3 and 4 are not correct for me: In spoken German you will have to use the Perfekt, and for me it would be hard to make up a written context where the Präteritum is acceptable. I think there are none, because the sentences are 'spoken by nature'. In real life spoken German you could say 3) _Ich hab' mir jetzt doch das billige Auto gekauft_ (und nicht das teure). 4) _Ich hab' das Auto billig (/ günstig) bekommen._

Comment: Interestingly, *arme Würstchen* (which is a popular idiom) cannot be be transposed (except perhaps ironically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The English sentence "I bought the car cheap." puts an adjective after the noun, but I don't think it's  recommended wording except colloquially. I'm thinking "cheap" here is shorthand for the adverbial phrase "at a low price", so it's really acting as more of an adverb than an adjective, though the phrasing only works if you put it at the end of the sentence.

Similarly, if not more so, *billig* is acting as adverb in the example *Ich kaufte das Auto billig.* Remember that in German, unlike English, you can usually use an adjective as an adverb with no suffix. So the proper translation into English would be "I bought the car cheaply." (See akuzminykh's note above.) Also note that because German allows sentence phrases to be moved around more than in English, you could put *billig* in other locations. For example, you could say *Billig kaufte ich das Auto,* without breaking the grammar. (I don't claim it doesn't sound odd though.) I'm not sure what to make of *Er isst die Würstchen warm.* Perhaps *warm* is meant to mean "while it's warm" as in might in English. Perhaps it is being used as a predicate as your grammar book claims, but in my (limited) experience predicative adjectives are used with copulative verbs in German: "Die Würstchen sind warm."

In general both English and German prefer adjectives in front of the thing they are describing. If you see an an adjective after a noun then it usually means that there's something else going on, for example a colloquialism, or, especially in German, that what you really have is an adverb.

Comment: In your last sentence, do you mean "..what you really have is an adverb"?  Thanks for the detailed reply!

Comment: @Satish Vasan: Yes, thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Many grammers don't give a complete description of the use of adjectives - nor will I. Instead, I'll give some examples. For further information it can be useful to look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_predicate and https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikativum#Freie_Pr%C3%A4dikativa.

1. *die schwarze Jacke*: *schwarze* = **attributives Adjektiv**
2. *Die Jacke ist schwarz.* [= Bedeutung wie in 1]: *schwarz* = prädikatives Adjektiv, hier **Subjektprädikativ**
3. *Er streicht den Stuhl schwarz.*: He is painting the chair black, *schwarz* = prädikatives (und resultatives) Adjektiv, hier **Objektprädikativ**; auch figurativ, nicht-resultativ: *Er sieht seine Zukunft schwarz.*, figurativ +resultativ: *Er ärgert sich schwarz über seine Nachbarn.* (is getting extremely angry about …; *schwarz* refers to *sich*, and *sich* is accusative; you can also say that as a last consequence it refers to the subject)
4. *Der Stift schreibt schwarz.*: *schwarz* = **Adverb zum Verb** *schreiben*; maybe the pen's outward is yellow, but the ink in it and the writing is black; many figurative uses meaning 'doing something illegal': *er arbeitet schwarz / er fährt schwarz / er hat den Schnaps schwarz gebrannt …*
5. *der schwarz gebrannte Schnaps*: **Adverb zum** partizipialen **Adjektiv** *gebrannt*; analog *der schwarz angestrichene Stuhl, das schwarz angemalte Gesicht …*
6. *er trinkt seinen Kaffee heute schwarz*: I think it's obvious that *schwarz* here is referring to the coffee in another sense than in 3 (he doesn't 'make' the coffee black) or in 4 (the drinking is not black) or in 5 (he doesn't drink it illegally). The meaning is: In the given situation (= *heute*) he is drinking his coffee without milk; it's a situational, time-bound quality of the coffee during the act of drinking it, and that is what English grammarians call a *secondary predicate* or *depictive*, in German **(Objekt)-Depiktiv** (nicht-resultatives Objekt-Prädikativ)
7. *Die Bergleute fahren am Montagmorgen sauber nach unten, und sie kommen am Abend schwarz zurück.* [see 6., but referring to the subject] = they are black when they are coming back up: **(Subjekt)-Depiktiv** (nicht-resultatives Sujekt-Prädikativ)

**Syntactical analogies with *frisch***

One difficult point is that *frisch* can have the meanings *recently, newly* as well as the meanings *fresh(ly)* and *just finished, just completed* and *looking and smelling new and still warm*, they all forming a sort of conglomerate whose elements are hardly separable.

1. *die frischen Tomaten* [= sie liegen noch nicht lange bei mir in der Küche herum]: *frischen* = **attributives Adjektiv**
2. *die Tomaten sind frisch* [= Bedeutung wie in 1]: *frisch* = **Subjektprädikativ**
3. *Wo ist Nadine? - Sie ist auf der Toilette, sie will sich ein wenig frischmachen.* [= sich waschen, ihr Make-Up auffrischen, neues Deo / Parfum auflegen ...]: *frisch* = **resultatives Objektprädikativ** zu *(sie) ... sich* = Herstellen des Zustands *frisch* an *sich*
4. 4a) *die Wäsche riecht frisch*: *frisch* = **Adverb** zu *riechen*, kann auch als Subjektprädikativ (ist frisch) verstanden werden; 4b) *ich habe die Tomaten frisch gepflückt* [= gerade erst / heute erst gepflückt]: *frisch* = **Adverb zum Verb** *habe ... gepflückt*; maybe the tomatoes are even old and not in good condition, but the picking has been finished not long ago; 4c) *Die Treppe ist frisch gestrichen*  = *newly painted* = **Adverb** zu *gestrichen*, und *frisch gestrichen* = Subjektprädikativ
5. *die frisch geernteten Tomaten*: **Adverb zum** partizipialen **Adjektiv** *geerntet*; analog *der frisch operierte Patient, das frisch verheiratete Brautpaar, die frisch erhaltenen Informationen* - They all are half-predicative, though, see 6.
6. *Du musst die Tomaten frisch essen, sonst schmecken sie nicht.* (= essen, solange sie noch frisch sind): **Depiktiv zum Objekt**
7. *Erdbeeren schmecken am besten frisch vom Feld* (= am besten direkt von der Pflanze in den Mund, so dass der Sand noch zwischen den Zähnen knirscht): **Depiktiv zum Subjekt**

---

Cf. *der Kaffee ist frisch gemahlen* = 4b); *er hat mir die Geschichte brühwarm weitererzählt* = 6; *die Brötchen kommen frisch aus dem Ofen* = sie sind noch warm = 7

**Other examples**

1. die *trockenen* Handtücher aus dem (Wäsche-) Trockner nehmen: **attributiv**
2. Stell den Wäschetrockner aus, die Wäsche ist jetzt *trocken*: **subjektprädikativ**
3. die Wäsche vor dem Aufhängen *trocken*schleudern / den Salat vor dem Anmachen *trocken*schleudern: **resultativ-objektprädikativ**
4. Lehrer: Sie sind wohl zu dumm, 2 + 2 zusammenzuzählen. - Schüler antwortet *trocken*: Ist doch ganz einfach - zweiundwzanzig!: **adverbial**
5. *kein Beispiel*
6. Die Handtücher erst *ganz trocken* aus der Maschine nehmen = *erst in dem Moment, wenn sie ganz trocken sind* (und nicht *halb-feucht*) = **Objekt-Depiktiv**

**Another set of examples**

1. die *warmen* Würstchen nicht wieder kalt werden lassen: **attributiv**
2. Die Würstchen sind *warm*, wie können jetzt essen!: **subjektprädikativ**
3. Ich hab' ihm die Würstchen *warm*gemacht [= *aufgewärmt*]: **resultativ-objektprädikativ**
4. Der Lehrer hat uns dieses Online-Wörterbuch sehr *warm* empfohlen. **adverbial**
5. *kein Beispiel*
6. Er wollte die Würstchen direkt *kalt* aus dem Glas essen, aber ich hab ihn gefragt, ob er die nicht lieber *warm* essen will : **objekt-depiktiv**

**Einer geht noch ;)**

1. Er kam wieder mit einer *billigen* Ausrede (*feeble excuse*): **attributiv**
2. Die Schuhe waren *billig*. (= 'preiswert, Nebenbedeutung 'von schlechter Qualität'): **prädikativ**
3. Er wollte diesen Handel für mich nicht *billiger* machen: **resultativ-objektprädikativ**
4. *kein Beispiel*
5. *kein Beispiel*
6. Er hat uns alles ganz *billig* renoviert. (= für wenig Geld): "*das alles Renoviert-Bekommen war billig*" = **Objektdepiktiv**?
7. Er ist nach dem Unfall *billig* davongekommen: (*Er musste nur eine ganz geringe Geldstrafe zahlen*) = für ihn war es 'billig', syntaktisch *er > billig*, dann **Subjektdepiktiv**?